# Extracting integer prices from different variants of budgets from Wikipedia

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing

I'm trying to use Python to call an API and clean a bunch of strings that represent a movie budget.

So far, I have the following 6 variants of data that come up.

1. "$1.2 million"
2. "$1,433,333"
3. "US$ 2 million"
4. "US$1,644,736 (est.)
5. "$6-7 million"
6. "£3 million"

So far, I've only gotten 1 and 2 parsed without a problem with the following code below. What is the best way to handle all of the other cases or a general case that may not be listed below?

```
def clean_budget_string(input_string):
number_to_integer = {'million' : 1000000, 'thousand' : 1000}
budget_parts = input_string.split(' ')
#Currently, only indices 0 and 1 are necessary for computation

text_part = budget_parts[1]

if text_part in number_to_integer:
    number = budget_parts[0].lstrip('$')
    int_representation = number_to_integer[text_part]
    return int(float(number) * int_representation)
else:
    number = budget_parts[0]
    idx_dollar = 0
    for idx in xrange(len(number)):
        if number[idx] == '$':
            idx_dollar = idx

    return int(number[idx_dollar+1:].replace(',', ''))
```

Comment: What should be the output of $6-7 million ?

Comment: 6000000 should be the output. For the in between, should just round down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would approach a parsing task like this -- and I'm happy to hear other opinions -- would be to break up your function into several parts, each of which identify a single piece of information in the input string.

For instance, I'd start by identifying what float number can be parsed from the string, ignoring currency and order of magnitude (a million, a thousand) for now :

`f = float(''.join([c for c in input_str if c in '0123456789.']))`

(you might want to add error handling for when you end up with a trailing dot, because of additions like 'est.')

Then, in a second step, you determine whether the float needs to be multiplied to adjust for the correct order of magnitude. One way of doing this would be with multiple if-statements :

```
if 'million' in input_str :
  oom = 6
elif 'thousand' in input_str :
  oom = 3
else :
  oom = 1

# adjust number for order of magnitude
f = f*math.pow(10, oom)
```

Those checks could of course be improved to account for small differences in formatting by using regular expressions.

Finally, you separately determine the currency mentioned in your input string, again using one or more if-statements :

```
if '£' in input_str :
  currency = 'GBP'
else :
  currency = 'USD'
```

Now the one case that this doesn't yet handle is the dash one where lower and upper estimates are given. One way of making the function work with these inputs is to split the initial input string on the dash and use the first (or second) of the substrings as input for the initial float parsing. So we would replace our first line of code with something like this:

```
if '-' in input_str :
  lower = input_str.split('-')[0]
  f = float(''.join([c for c in lower if c in '0123456789.']))
else :
  f = float(''.join([c for c in input_str if c in '0123456789.']))
```

Comment: This is amazing. I think though that the second list compression should also include a 0 so it should be if c in 0123456789. because there could be a case that is just "$1,288,000"

Answer (score 0):

using regex and string replace method, i added the return of the curency as well if needed.
Modify accordingly to handle more input or multiplier like billion etc.

```
import re
# take in string and return integer amount and currency
def clean_budget_string(s):
    mult_dict = {'million':1000000,'thousand':1000}
    tmp = re.search('(^\D*?)\s*((?:\d+\.?,?)+)(?:-\d+)?\s*((?:million|thousand)?)', s).groups()
    currency = tmp[0]
    mult = tmp[-1]
    tmp_int = ''.join(tmp[1:-1]).replace(',', '') # join digits and multiplier, remove comma
    tmp_int = int(float(tmp_int) * mult_dict.get(mult, 1))
    return tmp_int, currency


>>? clean_budget_string("$1.2 million")
(1200000, '$')
>>? clean_budget_string("$1,433,333")
(1433333, '$')
>>? clean_budget_string("US$ 2 million")
(2000000, 'US$')
>>? clean_budget_string("US$1,644,736 (est.)")
(1644736, 'US$')
>>? clean_budget_string("$6-7 million")
(6000000, '$')
>>? clean_budget_string("£3 million")
(3000000, '£') # my script don't recognize the £ char, might need to set the encoding properly
```